# Additive set functions: Are the definitions equivalent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$.

> Definition 1: An additive set function $\psi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function for which
>   $$\psi(\cup A_n) = \sum \psi (A_n)$$
>   if $A_1,A_2, \ldots$ is a finite or infinite sequence of disjoint sets.

It turns out that the sum of right hand side is absolutely convergent. This can be proved easily as any rearrangement of the sum yield the same result. But consider the following definition:

> Definition 2: An additive set function $\psi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function for which
>   $$\psi(\cup A_n) = \sum \psi (A_n)$$
>   if $A_1,A_2, \ldots$ is a finite or infinite sequence of disjoint sets and $\sum |\psi(A_n)| < \infty$.

My question: Are the above two definition equivalent?

Note that Definition 1 $\implies$ Definition 2 is obvious. But definition 2 looks at only those collection of sets for which $\sum |\psi(A_n)| < \infty$. Can we conclude from here that for any finite/ infinite disjoint sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ we have $\psi(\cup A_n) =\sum \psi(A_n)$?

I think it is not possible, however I didn't get any counterexample.

My try: Suppose $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ be disjoint sets such that $\sum |\psi(E_n)|=\infty$. WLOG we can get $n_1,n_2,\ldots $ such that $\psi(E_{n_k})\ge 0$ and $\sum \psi (E_{n_k})=\infty$ (or we may get a sequence of sets with negative values and sum = $-\infty$).

Then I thought of considering $\sigma(E_{n_k} : k\in \mathbb{N})$, but couldn't proceed further.

Any help or suggestions?